# Mips, continuous user input

Tags: loops, while-loop, io, conditional-statements, mips

How would I go about asking a user for continuous input? Basically I want to capture only numbers greater than 0, anything less than 0 I want to print an error message followed by the enter number message.

Comment: Write a loop using one or more conditional branches. Download _MIPS32™ Architecture For Programmers Volume II: The MIPS32™ Instruction Set_ if you don't already have it, and look through it for suitable instructions that you can use.

Answer (score 2):

How would you go about solving this in high-level language pseudocode? One way is -

```
while true
  print("Enter a number: ")
    n = read_a_number()
    if n < 0
      print("Error. Negative number")
    else
      # process the non-negative number (>= 0)
    # detect when to break while loop
```

Once the above is clear, it is fairly easy to translate this to MIPS.

```
.data
prompt: .asciiz "Enter a number: "
error:  .asciiz "Error. Negative number\n"

.text
while:
la   $a0, prompt                    # print prompt to enter a number
li   $v0, 4                         # $v0 = 4 to print string with address in $a0
syscall

li   $v0, 5                         # to read an int. Read in $v0
syscall

bltz $v0, negative                  # is the input negative?
j    non_negative                   # else, handle non_negative

negative:
la   $a0, error                     # print error
li   $v0, 4
syscall
j    next                           # and goto 'next'

non_negative:
# process the non-negative number (>= 0)
j    next                           # and goto 'next'

next:
# detect when to break while loop (or do that at the start of the loop)
j    while                          # continue loop

after_while:                        # after the loop
li   $v0, 10                        # $v0=10 to exit
syscall
```

Answer (score 0):

> You initialize counter and avoid multiple 'syscall' like this:

```
.data 
    ###Set your maximum loop value
    max_count:  .word   10

.text main:
    ###Initialize the counter from 1
    ###Using $t0: first temporary location
    lw     $t0,    1

while_loop:
    ###Load the maximum count value
    lw     $t1,    max_count

    ###Compare the counter with the maximum count
    ###If $t0 >= $t1 then exit_loop
    bge    $t0,    $t1,    exit_loop

    ###Increment the counter by 1
    addi   $t0,    $t0,    1

    ###Repeat the loop
    j      while_loop

exit_loop:
    ###Exit the program
    ###you can use code 10 in $v0 to terminate execution
    li     $v0,    10
    syscall
```

Comment: If $t0 and $t1 confuses you, then replace $t0 with i, and $t1 with j.